# Looking for help to express an xcm destination oftype VersionedMultiLocation

Tags: xcm, transfer, orml-xtokens

I am trying to write a rust function that will call the transfer extrinsic function from pallet orml_xtokens.
I am looking for help in translating the destination described in the image below.
dest: XcmVersionedMultiLocation = V1
V1: XcmV1MultiLocation =
junction of
parents 1
interior X1
X1 Junction = AccountID
Network = Any
AccountID32 = an address

[image]

Comment: Where do you actually want to transfer your KSM to?

Comment: The destination is the account ID in the image (5ECMd...) *on the parent chain*. This might resolve into a different account on the local chain and is determined by the XCM configuration of the local chain (specifically the `SovereignAccountOf` type).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to express the above call:

```rust
use crate::metadata::runtime_types::xcm::{
    v1::junction::Junction,
    v0::junction::NetworkId,
    v1::multilocation::Junctions::X1,
    v1::multilocation::MultiLocation as V1MultiLocation,
    VersionedMultiLocation as VersionedMultiLocation,
};

let dest : &VersionedMultiLocation = &VersionedMultiLocation::V1(
                V1MultiLocation {
                    parents: 1,
                    interior: X1(
                        Junction::AccountId32 {
                            network: NetworkId::Any,
                            id: dest_account.into(),
                        }
                    ),
                }
            );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).